# Cannot read InputStream from HttpListenerRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome-extension

I've been creating download manager that receive file name and download link from chrome extension.
In this case I decided to use javascript background page to send XMLHttpRequest to loopback and create simple server to receive message the background page look like this.

background.js

```js
function showMessageBox(info, tab) {
    var link = decodeURIComponent(info.linkUrl);
    var index = link.search(/[^/\\\?]+\.\w{3,4}(?=([\?&].*$|$))/);
    var fileName = link.substring(index);
    alert("will download from " + link + " soon\n File name : " + fileName);
    SendMessage(fileName,link);
}
function SendMessage(fileName, link) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:6230", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    var JSONstring = JSON.stringify({ FileName: fileName, DownloadLink: link });
    xhr.send(JSONstring);
}
```

and the part of server.

```
    private void StartReciever()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var fileInfo = GetFileInfo();
            Execute.OnUIThread(() => WindowManager.ShowDialog(
                new NewDownloadViewModel(WindowManager, EventAggregator, fileInfo, Engine)));
        }
    }

    private FileInfo GetFileInfo()
    {
        using (var listener = new HttpListener())
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:6230/");
            listener.Start();
            var requestContext = listener.GetContext();
            /*var streamReader = new StreamReader(requestContext.Request.InputStream, requestContext.Request.ContentEncoding);
            string jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();*/
            var stream = requestContext.Request.InputStream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            var readbyte = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 102400);
            string ss = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, readbyte);
            // deserialize string to object

            return new FileInfo();
        }
    }
```

I wonder why stream read always return 0 when message was sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found what I forgot!

According to [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), I can't send http request to server that isn't the same origin.
I must use [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) to communicate to server that isn't the same origin.

To do that I need to [Request cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) by add hostname to permissions section.
In my case I look like this.

```
"permissions": [
"contextMenus",
"http://localhost/",
"nativeMessaging"
]
```

Now, I can receive string and deserialize it.